# Finding the maximum subsequence between 2 strings

Tags: python

Given 2 strings, find the maximum character overlap in-sequence between the 2 strings.

For example:

1. "klccconcertcenter"
2. "klconventioncenter"

The maximum overlap in-sequence is "klconetcenter"

Here it is exemplified:

1. **klc**cc**on**c**e**r**tcenter**
2. **klcon**v**e**n**t**ion**center**

---

BTW, this is not homework. I'm actually using this in production to test how similar 2 strings are. For example, comparing "ABC Pte Ltd" and "ABC Private Limited", I will take the maximum in-sequence overlap, divided by the length shorter string, for a 0-1 rating of how relevant these 2 strings are.

I actually have a solution for this, but it's an approximation. My naive recursive method doesn't scale for long strings.

---

Ok since people are asking for my solution:

```
def match_count(phrase1, phrase2):
    """This approximates match_count_recur() because the recursive function does not scale for long strings"""
    MAX_MATCH_COUNT_WIDTH = 15
    if len(phrase1) > MAX_MATCH_COUNT_WIDTH:
        return match_count(phrase1[:len(phrase1) / 2], phrase2) + match_count(phrase1[len(phrase1) / 2:], phrase2)
    return match_count_recur(phrase1, phrase2)


def match_count_recur(phrase1, phrase2):
    """
    Checks the number of characters that intersect (in order) between 2 phrases
    """
    if len(phrase2) < 1: return 0
    if len(phrase1) < 1: return 0
    if len(phrase1) == 1: return 1 if phrase1 in phrase2 else 0
    if len(phrase2) == 1: return 1 if phrase2 in phrase1 else 0
    if phrase1 in phrase2: return len(phrase1)
    if phrase2 in phrase1: return len(phrase2)

    char = phrase1[0]
    current_count = 1 if char in phrase2 else 0
    phrase2_idx = phrase2.index(char) + 1 if char in phrase2 else 0

    no_skip_count = current_count + match_count(phrase1[1:], phrase2[phrase2_idx:])
    skip_count = match_count(phrase1[1:], phrase2)

    return max(no_skip_count, skip_count)

def get_similarity_score(phrase1, phrase2):
    """
    Gets the similarity score of 2 phrases
    """
    phrase1 = phrase1.lower().replace(" ", "")
    phrase2 = phrase2.lower().replace(" ", "")
    shorter_phrase = phrase2
    longer_phrase = phrase1
    if len(phrase1) < len(phrase2):
        shorter_phrase = phrase1
        longer_phrase = phrase2
    return float(match_count(shorter_phrase, longer_phrase)) / float(len(shorter_phrase))
```

Comment: You probably want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance for which there'll definitely be an existing Python implementation.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's homework or not - you've still not shown any of your working. You should provide evidence of your work to allow users to try to work out why your method "doesn't scale for long strings"

Comment: @asongtoruin where's the faith? edited and added my solution

Comment: @ceejayoz it's not levenshtein dist. KLCC and KLConventionCenter should return a match of 1. Levenshtein will fail for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that you are trying to solve the longest subsequence problem ([wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)). [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence) has a Python implementation that might be interesting to look at.

There is also a builtin in Python that implements something like this, in the `difflib` module. In particular, the `difflib.Differ` class.

Comment: Seems like my existing solution actually solves the problem. It's just slow (if the strings are super long), given the complexity of the problem.

Comment: The problem is possible to solve in quadratic time (time needed grows as the product of the length of each string), so it is not actually _that_ complex. A smart approach (see the links) would likely give a large gain.